# FXML Boiler Plate Code

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

Is there a way to address a typical boiler plate code to instantiate and load FXML?

A typical version:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{   
    URL fxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource( /* your string path*/ );

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);

    try 
    {   
        primaryStage = loader.load();
        this.controller = loader.getController();
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note for the code above, the backing FXML file has `<Stage></Stage>` as root.  This is just my preference.  The loading and matching up to the FXML root can adjust accordingly.  In any case, the loading of the FXML file and obtaining reference to a controller is the crucial part (for most of the time).

I've attempted to create a utility method such the one below to help prevent this boiler plate code:

```
<R, C> void loadFXML(R root, C controller, String path)
{
    URL fxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource( path );

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);

    try 
    {   
        root = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, at some stage there was null pointer errors, or the loading was incorrect.  I believe it has something to do with the Generics and/or casting.

How can the this code be imporoved?  Or perhap can another type code be suggested to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (probably; you don't show where your Null Pointer Exceptions are coming from) that you merely set the local variables `root` and `controller`, and then let them go out of scope.

Remember that Java handles method parameters in a pass-by-value manner: so the method creates local copies of the `root` and `controller` references. When your method invokes

```
root = loader.load();
controller = loader.getController();
```

it just updates the local references, not the references that were passed to the method. So if you do

```
Parent root = null ;
MyController controller = null ;
loadFXML(root, controller, "Main.fxml");
System.out.println(root);
System.out.println(controller);
```

you will see the values `null`.

One fix is to pass in mutable wrappers for the objects, and update those wrappers. `ObjectProperty` works for this:

```
<R, C> void loadFXML(String path, ObjectProperty<R> root, ObjectProperty<C> controller)
{
    URL fxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource( path );

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);

    try 
    {   
        root.set(loader.load());
        controller.set(loader.getController());
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Another option is to create a class that encapsulates the two values and return an instance of it:

```
public class ViewController<V,C> {
    private final V view ;
    private final C controller ;
    public ViewController(V view, C controller) {
        this.view = view ;
        this.controller = controller ;
    }
    public V getView() {
        return view ;
    }
    public C getController() {
        return controller ;
    }
}
```

and then

```
<R, C> ViewController<R, C> loadFXML(String path)
{
    URL fxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource( path );

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);

    try 
    {   
        R root = loader.load();
        C controller = loader.getController();
        return new ViewController<R,C>(root, controller);
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe); // this is likely fatal, so just throw an unchecked exception
    }
}
```

It's arguable whether or not you get any savings in terms of verbosity though:

```
ViewController<Parent, MyController> viewController = loadFXML("Main.fxml");
Parent root = viewController.getView();
MyController controller = viewController.getController();
```

A final observation is that in almost all use cases you really only do any significant work with the controller afterwards; you typically just set the view as the root of the scene, or add it to another layout pane. You could leverage this (in Java 8) by having the method accept a `Consumer<R>` and return the controller:

```
public <R, C> C loadFXML(Consumer<R> rootHandler, String path) {
    URL fxmlUrl = this.getClass().getResource( path );

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);

    try 
    {   
        R root = loader.load();
        C controller = loader.getController();
        rootHandler.accept(root);
        return controller ;
    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe); // this is likely fatal, so just throw an unchecked exception
    }
}
```

which you would invoke using something like

```
Scene scene = new Scene();
MyController controller = loadFXML(scene::setRoot, "Main.fxml");
```

Comment: For the method signature: `<R,C> void loadFxml(R root, C controller, String path)`, the method argument `Root root` and `C controller` suppose to contain reference to the fxml root and its controller (respectively) after the loading process.  However, the reference to loaded fxml root and its controller is not set to the argument reference passed in.

Comment: RE: typo: Root root ; should be: R Root

Comment: That's simply not how method parameters work in Java. See update.

Comment: Thanks James_D.  That clears it up.  You're probably right in deciding whether to have the utility class and method vs the verbosity.  I would probably end up having one just for readability.  I appreciate what you've written.  I would vote up, but I'm new to stackoverflow.com and don't have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: I think you can accept the answer, though, if you want.